# MySQL UNION ALL ORDER BY Column not In SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union-all

I'm trying to finish a query, but am having issues with the `ORDER BY` at the end. Here is an Example:

```
SELECT 
  fieldA, fieldB
FROM
  tableA
WHERE [conditionA]

UNION ALL

SELECT
  fieldA, fieldB
FROM tableA
WHERE [conditionB]

ORDER BY fieldA, fieldC
```

`fieldC` is not included in either `SELECT`, but exists within the tables I'm using. Normally, in a standard `SELECT`, this can easily be accomplished.

Answer (score 4):

The `ORDER BY` is conceptually *after* the `UNION ALL`.  It can only reference columns that are `SELECT`ed.  So, do this with a subquery:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM ((SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
       FROM tableA
       WHERE [conditionA]
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
       FROM tableA
       WHERE [conditionB]
     )
    ) a
ORDER BY fieldA, fieldC;
```

Given that the logic is for the same table, it is likely that this would do what you want as well:

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB
FROM tableA
WHERE [conditionA] OR 
      [conditionB]
ORDER BY fieldA, fieldC;
```

Comment: unfortunately, the select statements actually differ, with one of them using aggregated functions, but I think your first example may work